# Distance Finding in ASP.net No Error is Found But Also No Required result is Found

Tags: asp.net, web, model-view-controller

I used have this script code in ASP.net MVC View file also included jQuery and Google Maps reference files. It shows no error no warnings as well as no required result in Browser. Is it OK?
What should I do? I need distance in kilometers as well as placeholder with location hints while typing address. Multiple locations also can be handled.
Any API that can do this. Thanks For Your Precious Opinions.
(*I found this is an easy way to find distance but it disappointed me.)

HTML CODE

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&language=en&key=AIzaSyDG1cZyGRlcAyUgpVpr5x5xadfKSTLFEjs"></script>

<form id="distance_form">
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Origin:</label>
    <input id="form_places" class="form-control" placeholder="Pick up location" />
    <input id="origin" type="hidden" name="origin" required />

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Destination:</label>
    <input id="to_places" class="form-control" placeholder="Pick up destination" />
    <input id="destination" type="hidden" name="destination" required />
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Calculate" class="btn btn-Primary" />
 </form>
 <div id="result"></div>
```

Script Code

```
<script>
   (function () {
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
        var form_places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('form_places'));
        var to_places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('to_places'));

    google.maps.event.addListener(form_places, 'place_changed', function () {
        var form_place = form_place.getPlace();
        var form_address = form_place.formatted_address;
        $('origin').val(form_address);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(to_places, 'place_changed', function () {
        var to_place = to_place.getPlace();
        var to_address = to_place.formatted_address;
        $('destination').val(to_address);
    });
});

function CalculateDistance() {
    var origin = $('origin').val();
    var destination = $('destination').val();
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix(
        {
            origin: ['origin'],
            destination: ['destination'],
            travelmode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.metric,
            avoidHighways: false,
            avoidTolls: false
        }, callback);
}
   //get destance result
function callback(response, status) {
    if (!google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
        $('result').html(err);
    } else {
        var origin = response.originAddresses[0];
        var destination = response.destinationAddresses[0];
        if (response.rows[0].elements[0].status === "ZERO_RESULTS") {
            $('result').html('No roads between' + origin + 'and ' + destination)
        } else {
            var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance;
            var duration = response.rows[0].elements.duration;
            console.log(response.rows[0].elements[0].distance);
            var distance_in_Kilo = distance.value / 1000;
            var duration_text = duration.text;
            var duration_value = duration.value;
            $('#in_kilo').text(distance_in_kilo.ToFixed(2));
            $('#duration_text').text(duration_text.ToFixed(2));
            $('#duration_value').text(duration_value.ToFixed(2));
            $('#form').text(origin);
            $('#to').text(destination);

        }
    }
}
//submit button
$('#distance_form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    CalculateDistance();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: give us HTML code also

Comment: sir i have added HTML Waiting for response

Comment: Now It Have error [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler

Comment: First are you sure your API key is correct? as for me its giving error "APINotActivatedMapError" .
Second HTML code is trying to submit form to some action just remove button type from **submit** to **Button** so you can call javascript to calculate distance. 
Third: There is not text field with id or name "in_kilo" in which you are trying to show distance.

Comment: Here you can see **example** (with sample code) of calculating **distance** here (http://jsbin.com/amodAJuQ/1/edit?html,console,output).

Comment: I have made changes as you describe but still no result find